# How to bring a </div> closer to its <div> using React/Angular/Vue?

Tags: html, angular, reactjs, vue.js, code-organization

**Prelude**

Seasoned C (say) developers will squirm at the sight of a 200-line function. They will strive to divide it into (say) ten functions of 20 lines each. Loosely speaking, the objective is for a function to never cross one screen.

**Context** (update)

If a desktop (C, say) application is written modularly, it's possible to locate a bug easily. Look in all functions called by `main`. Identify the culprit; look inside; recurse. By comparison HTML development is a nightmare. When a flaw is discovered or an improvement is needed, it's very hard to narrow the scope of what should be modified. Is there a better tool for modularity than server-side templates or a client-side library? Are React/Angular/Vue suitable for the job? How?

**Motivation**

Web developers face the same issue. It is desirable for the lines between an opening `<div>` and its corresponding closing `</div>` to never cross one screen. If the two cannot be simultaneously seen in one screen, it is much harder to keep a good mental image of the code.

A templating engine, say [Jinja](https://www.palletsprojects.com/p/jinja/), can be used to split an HTML file.

For example, with a file

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="left">
        <!-- many lines -->
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <!-- many lines -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Jinja's derivation can be used to split the HTML file to a parent and child files.

```
<div class="main">
    {% block left %}
    {% endblock %}
    {% block right %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>

{% extends "main.html" %}
{% block left %}
    <!-- many lines -->
{% endblock %}
{% block right %}
    <!-- many lines -->
{% endblock %}
```

This is satisfying in a way reminiscent of splitting functions in, say, the C language. There the hallmark of ugliness in a long function is that indentation *also* becomes excessive, and then it also becomes difficult to see exactly where a loop begins and ends.

The [D3.js](https://d3js.org) can likewise be used. The HTML file above becomes a pair of HTML and JS files.

```
<div class="main">
</div>

let main = d3.select("main")
let left = main.append("div")
               .attr("class", "left");
let right = main.append("div")
                .attr("class", "right");
```

(Or, for industrial-strength use of D3 for this objective, see [here](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/).)

**Question**

Neither of these solutions feels right. They feel like using a powerful tool to do something quite simple, and a newcomer to the code (or oneself after an absence) does not see with lucidity something that is otherwise nearly trivial.

How can the first HTML file above be split using `React/Angular/Vue` to make sure that `<div class="main">` and its closing `</div>` remain only a few lines apart no matter how much code goes into the left and right DIVs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a really thoughtful question. I feel that my answer is a bit simple, so perhaps I misunderstood the goal of your question.

React and Vue leverage components to organize templates and abstract away the complexity of the DOM. You can encapsulate as much behavior as you'd like inside of these components.

From a Vue POV (though react has similar tools to accomplish the same goals)... if you're going for fewer lines of code, you could encapsulate the entirety of the "left" and "right" (their behavior, styles, and templates) as components*. If the two components do not share any state or data, this becomes very simple and clear as you do not need to pass any props down.

---

**Code example (in Vue)**

This is an overly simple example and usually `MyPage.vue` would have additional behavior, such as loading, animations, or setting up the initial app's data.

```js
// MyPage.vue
<template>
    <div>
         <v-left/>
         <v-right/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import VRight from '@/components/right.vue';
import VLeft from '@/components/left.vue';

export default {
    components: {
        VRight,
        VLeft
    }
}
</script>
```

---

Finally, this might be a bit too covered in Vue terminology, but for some great illustrations of code organization (for any language or framework) are in [this document](https://vue-composition-api-rfc.netlify.com/#code-organization).

The measure of code complexity is not only in lines of code in a given function but also in the number of places you need to touch when implementing something or the risk of breaking other areas of the code.

One of the most brittle areas of frontend code is CSS, this is why packaging CSS with components (either using a CSS-in-JS approach or using Vue's scoped styles) makes a huge improvement in the stability and reusability of the code you write.

I hope this was helpful!!

* (there are reasons why doing this isn't the best choice in a lot of cases)

Comment: Since for developers CSS is often the Achilles heel of web development, the point you're making about React/Angular/Vue enabling CSS scoping is most compelling. You're also implicitly asking and answering another nice question ("What can React/Angular/Vue do for me that I cannot already do with either Jinja or D3?").

Comment: But for the sake of closing one point, I'm having trouble running your code (by prefixing with `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>`). What am I missing?

Comment: if this answer would contain a comparison to react/angular it would be a perfect anwer imho. Angular will not solve your problem as it is a whole framework, giving you more than you bargained for, where vue and react are both lightweight and frontedn-focused. Vue expecially can be exported to WebComponents, suported by html5 allowing you to write your main pages in regular html whilst using vue components in them

Comment: @Calaf your problem is that this is a vue component and either needs to be compiled or loaded onto an html element using vue: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/ for more info

Comment: @miThom - I haven't taken the time to learn React syntax yet, so it wasn't on the tip of my tongue. The concepts of modular, reusable components transfer across any frontend framework though :-)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your question, I think you can obtain what you are after also using [Svelte](https://svelte.dev), which has similar goals to React/Vue but for some aspects is more a component compiler than a framework.

The official [tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/basics) is very quick to read/play with and teaches almost everything there is to know.

In your case you can look at this [playground](https://svelte.dev/repl/c81ec7d2d12141cdba3a6cf9a90f263f?version=3.16.0):

App.svelte - main application file

```html
<script>
    import Main from './Main.svelte';
    import Left from './Left.svelte';
    import Right from './Right.svelte';
</script>

<Main>
    <Left />
    <Right />
</Main>
```

Main.svelte - `<Main>` component (`<slot>` represents the contents from the caller of the component - in this case it contains the "calls" to Left and Right)

```html
<style>
...
</style>

<div class="main">
    <slot></slot>
</div>
```

Left.svelte - `<Left>` component

```html
<script>
    import Box from './Box.svelte';
</script>

<Box title="Left">
    <p>
    ...
    </p>
</Box>
```

Right.svelte is essentially equal to Left.svelte

Box.svelte - common `<Box>` inner component used by both `<Left>` and `<Right>`

```html
<script>
    export let title = "box";
</script>

<style>
    ...
</style>

<div class="box">
    <h3>
        {title}
    </h3>
    <slot></slot>
</div>
```

(here the parts common to Left and Right are factored into a Box component, but this is obviously not necessary)

For the sake of completeness, to turn the example into a complete program:

main.js

```js
import App from './App.svelte';

const app = new App({
    target: document.body,
});

export default app;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "svelte-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "dev": "rollup -c -w",
    "start": "sirv public"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "rollup": "^1.12.0",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^10.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-livereload": "^1.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^5.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-svelte": "^5.0.3",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^5.1.2",
    "svelte": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "sirv-cli": "^0.4.4"
  }
}
```

rollup.config.js:

```js
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

export default {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: {
        sourcemap: true,
        format: 'iife',
        name: 'app',
        file: 'public/build/bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        svelte({
            // enable run-time checks when not in production
            dev: !production,
            // we'll extract any component CSS out into
            // a separate file — better for performance
            css: css => {
                css.write('public/build/bundle.css');
            }
        }),

        // If you have external dependencies installed from
        // npm, you'll most likely need these plugins. In
        // some cases you'll need additional configuration —
        // consult the documentation for details:
        // https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs
        resolve({
            browser: true,
            dedupe: importee => importee === 'svelte' || importee.startsWith('svelte/')
        }),
        commonjs(),

        // In dev mode, call `npm run start` once
        // the bundle has been generated
        !production && serve(),

        // Watch the `public` directory and refresh the
        // browser on changes when not in production
        !production && livereload('public'),

        // If we're building for production (npm run build
        // instead of npm run dev), minify
        production && terser()
    ],
    watch: {
        clearScreen: false
    }
};

function serve() {
    let started = false;

    return {
        writeBundle() {
            if (!started) {
                started = true;

                require('child_process').spawn('npm', ['run', 'start', '--', '--dev'], {
                    stdio: ['ignore', 'inherit', 'inherit'],
                    shell: true
                });
            }
        }
    };
}
```

and then:

```sh
npm install
npm run dev
```

(please note that this is very essentially what the official svelte templeate creates using `npx degit sveltejs/template my-svelte-project`, as decribed on the landing page)

The nice thing is that Svelte compiles to standard JavaScript classes, so it's possible to use its components from regulard JavaScript. It's a no-framework framework from this point of view. See for example [this article](https://jimmyutterstrom.com/blog/2019/06/21/svelte-3-components-in-legacy-apps/)

Comment: Svelte seems to be a lightweight solution for exactly the problem described. Do I understand correctly that one needs a suitable `package.json`? And then running `npm install` and `npm run dev` will launch a local server? You have provided a complete app. Could you also add a few lines to describe what else is needed to test drive Svelte with your code?

Comment: @Calaf sure, I've added the relevant `package.json`, `rollup.config.js` and info. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the same issue with many old and modern frameworks, they don't take into consideration components and component re-use. In particular, if you want to include data elements, and say you want `left` to be a mailing address and `right` to be a shipping address, it's very difficult to create a common component like `address` to be used for both on the same form at the same time and have the data handled robustly.

You can go by order, for example for inputs of `name="street"`, the data will be an array with `[0]` likely on the left and `[1]` on the right, but you have to be careful handling for nulls, and if the form is redesigned, the data may not end up going in the right place for update operations.

I know it's ancient, but I've found ExtJS to be a very good framework for working with components and handling data. The equivalent to your HTML might be:

```
{
    name: 'main',
    xtype: 'left-and-right',
    leftItem: {
        name: 'mailing'
        xtype: 'address'
    },
    rightItem: {
        name: 'shipping',
        xtype: 'address'
    }
}
```

Obviously, there needs to be some more smarts to propagate `name`, but all that's handled behind the scenes, so you can reference `mailing.street` or `shipping.street` and not have to worry about nulls and form redesigns.

Unfortunately, ExtJS is basically moribund, now owned by a company known for all the wrong reasons, and all the relevant developers have left, so wouldn't suggest trying that path.

[Google Polymer](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer) is kind of in the right direction, and it's framework agnostic, so it might be a good option to use with any of the modern frameworks. Again, if you're using it for data, you might need to build in the smarts to propagate `name`.

Comment: So IIUC you're actually saying a lot: 1- React/Angular/Vue _cannot_ be used for this objective. 2- You're recommending 2/3 alternatives that would help with HTML5 modularity. 3- You're saying that the two issues are orthogonal; and hence one can use one of React/Angular/Vue with one of ExtJS/PolymerElement/LitElement. Is that right?

Comment: @Calaf Yes, although with the caveat that I'm not a seasoned expert in those frameworks. For sure, I wouldn't go with ExtJS, although they are peddling components heavily these days, it's uncertain how long they will last, and that framework has a huge learning curve, for what will likely be a dead end.

Answer (score 0):

*"How can the first HTML file above be split using React/Angular/Vue to make sure that  and its closing  remain only a few lines apart no matter how much code goes into the left and right DIVs?"*

JSX (XML dialect that compiles to JS code that creates virtual DOM elements) accomplishes this well. It's used in React and sometimes Vue.

To build on your C example that used many functions, that is exactly what we are doing here. Every JSX tag represents a function that returns another function or some UI element(s). Instead of putting everything in `<App />`, we can split `<App />` into the `<Main />`, `<Left />`, and `<Right />` functions:

```
const App = props => (
  <Main>
    <Left />
    <Right />
  </Main>
)

ReactDOM.render('.app', <App />);
```

To answer the main question, is that one of the raison deetres of these frameworks? IMHO no, it's just a shorthand for expressing calls to create vdom elements, since it's easier to write `<App />` than nested `React.creatElement({...etc})` all over the place. Since it just happens to represent functions, it does match the idea you mentioned in your prelude. But I think it was just created as a convenience for creating vdom elements/HTML-in-JS, not expressly as a templating engine (of which there are many!)

Comment: Library modularity is as at least as helpful while developing as C-code modularity or HTML code modularity. Yet I have trouble finding a way to use JSX that is detached from React et al. Is it possible to use JSX all by itself? (And in case it matters, consider someone living on the bleeding edge who cares only about the few most compliant recent browsers.)

Comment: I don't have any firsthand experience with that, but apparently (thanks for making me look btw!) it's easy to do using pragma comments: https://medium.com/@bluepnume/jsx-is-a-stellar-invention-even-with-react-out-of-the-picture-c597187134b7. Another neat application I found outside of React was rendering HTML5 canvas elements declaratively (found this on Github somewhere). As far as compatibility goes, I think you would just need babel configured build-side, should be good even for older browsers :)

Comment: I didn't add enough context to the question: If a desktop (C, say) application is written modularly, it's possible to locate a bug in a finite time. Look in all functions called by `main`. Identify the culprit; look inside; recurse. By comparison HTML development is a nightmare. When a flaw is discovered or an improvement is needed, it's very hard to narrow the scope of what needs to be modified. Is there a better tool for modularity than server-side templates or a client-side library? Are React/Angular/Vue suitable for the job? How?

Comment: I think React/JSX comes closest to achieving your goal. Disclaimer, some people just end up hating it. But you get to operate on the level of functions instead of strings, even for what appear to be regular ol' HTML elements. Your render tree, starting from your root elements (AKA main function) is just a call stack and debuggable as such. You get prop-type checking, linting, and even static typing if you're into that (via Typescript). And many flaws discovered in the browser become compile-time errors or warnings. If there's anything weird in the UI I can just use the React Devtools to

Comment: examine React XML elements (instead of HTML elements) and inspect the inputs/state and make sure everything adds up. When you add in stuff like Redux or Mobx the developer experience gets even better. Vue is great in this area too.